# Displaying winner's name in picture box

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

Below is code for a simple voting system I am coding.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim winner As String
    Dim maxVotes As Integer
    Dim votes() As String
    Dim index As String
    Dim candidates As String

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        If Not isValidInput(txtNewCandidate.Text) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        lstCandidates.Items.Add(txtNewCandidate.Text)
        txtNewCandidate.Clear()
        txtNewCandidate.Focus()
        ReDim Preserve votes(index)
        index += 1
    End Sub

    Private Function isValidInput(ByRef firstName As String) As Boolean
        If IsNumeric(txtNewCandidate.Text) Or txtNewCandidate.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please input a valid candidate name.")
            txtNewCandidate.Focus()
            Return False
        Else
            Return True
        End If
    End Function

    Private Sub btnTally_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTally.Click
        lstTallies.Visible = True
        lblTally.Visible = True
        For i = 0 To lstCandidates.Items.Count - 1
            lstTallies.Items.Add(lstCandidates.Items(i).ToString & " - " & votes(i))
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub lstCandidates_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstCandidates.DoubleClick
        If lstCandidates.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
            MsgBox("Select a candidate by double-clicking")
        End If
        votes(lstCandidates.SelectedIndex) += 1
        MsgBox("Vote Tallied")
    End Sub

    Private Sub pbxWinner_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles pbxWinner.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

The voter must double click on their choice of candidate in the first list box. The user then tallies the votes by clicking on a button and a second list box will appear with the votes per candidate.

Now I need to display the winner (or winners, if there is a tie) in a picture box, pbxWinner. I am not sure how to accomplish this. Any clues?

Here is what i am trying to do, though the code below doesn't work.

```
Private Function candidateWinner(ByRef winner As String) As Boolean
    For i As Integer = 0 To lstCandidates.SelectedIndex - 1
        If votes(i) > maxVotes Then
            maxVotes += 1
        End If
    Next
    g = pbxWinner.CreateGraphics
    g.TranslateTransform(10.0F, 0.0F)
    g.DrawString(winner, New Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.DarkBlue, New PointF(0, 0))
    Return True
End Function
```

Comment: A Picturebox does not have a `Text` property.  Use something more appropriate like a label

Answer (score 1):

Your code is actually working fine for an initial paint, but when the picture box image doesn't have its own bitmap set, a number of events can repaint its graphics behind the scenes(even as simple as minimizing/mazimizing the form, and a whole bunch of other ones), so in effect your text seems to never appear at all or disappear almost instantly when in reality it's probable getting repainted. To fix this, use a bitmap for the graphics object's reference, paint the bitmap's graphics, and then assign the bitmap to the picturebox's image property. This will make the image persistent...give this code a try in your candidateWinner function after the for loop:

```
Dim bmp As New Bitmap(pbxWinner.Width, pbxWinner.Height)
Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
g.TranslateTransform(10.0F, 0.0F)
g.DrawString(winner, New Font("arial", 7, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.DarkBlue, 0, 0)
pbxWinner.Image = bmp
```

...If you still aren't seeing text, make sure the winner string has the correct value set, I tested this code and it showed my test string correctly

---

Edit for Comment:

That's because of the logic you're using to calculate the winner...you are just checking to see if the currently selected candidate's vote count is higher than maxVotes and then incrementing the max by 1. If you wanted to stick with that sort of logic for picking the winner, you would want to iterate through ALL of the candidates(not just those from index 0 to the currently selected one), and if their vote count is higher than the max, then set the max EQUAL to their vote count. Then the next candidate in the loop will have their count checked against the previous max. However, tracking the winner could be done a lot easier if you just use a dictionary since you are allowing candidates to be added, and you must change your "winner" logic to actually check who has the most votes out of everyone entered. A bare bones example of that would look like this:

```
Dim dctTally As Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    dctTally = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
End Sub

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    dctTally.Add(txtNewCandidate.Text, 0)
    lstCandidates.Items.Add(txtNewCandidate.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub lstCandidates_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstCandidates.DoubleClick
    dctTally(lstCandidates.text) += 1
End Sub

Private Sub pbxWinner_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles pbxWinner.Click
    Dim winner = dctTally.Aggregate(Function(l, r) If(l.Value > r.Value, l, r)).Key
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(pbxWinner.Width, pbxWinner.Height)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
    g.TranslateTransform(10.0F, 0.0F)
    g.DrawString(winner, New Font("arial", 7, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.DarkBlue, 0, 0)
    pbxWinner.Image = bmp
End Sub
```

This way, the program allows as many names as you want to be added to the candidates list, and will add a vote count to their name each time their name is double-clicked on. Then, when your winner pixturebox is clicked, it will find the dictionary with the highest vote count and display their name in the winner-box.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to draw the winners:

```
Private Sub candidateWinner()

    Dim y As Single = 0

    maxVotes = votes.Select(Function(x) Convert.ToInt32(x)).Max()

    For i = 0 To UBound(votes)
        If votes(i) = maxVotes.ToString() Then
            g = pbxWinner.CreateGraphics
            g.TranslateTransform(10.0F, 0.0F)
            g.DrawString(lstCandidates.Items(i).ToString(), New Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.DarkBlue, New PointF(0, y))
            y += 10
            g.Dispose()
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```